# i have published my asp.net core 3 to iis, but hitting the directory and not showing me the site index.cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, localhost, publishing

ASP.NET CORE 3 MVC Published website on IIS manager, when going to the url it shows me the directory of the folder rather then the website,
i have set the directory browsing as enabled on the iis
given all permissions to the file location and folder location

Comment: MVC framework mandates URL patterns so that controllers/views can be resolved. So you cannot use arbitrary URL and expect a page to be shown (.cshtml is a view, not a simple web page). Go through the tutorials and learn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#how-controllers-specify-views

Comment: I suggest you could also post the IIS web site's folder makeup and application startup.cs's route and endpoint settings. Maybe you used the wrong setting in it.